# OpenLiteSpeed - Changing Document Root and Permissions

Tags: litespeed

I am trying to change the document root on my Ubtuntu 18.04 OpenLiteSpeed server. I would like to change it to `/var/www/html/public` so I can install my Laravel project there. It's where I am used to having my document root from Apache. I have found the settings within the admin panel (it is now set to `/var/www/html/public`); however, it seems from other posts that I have found that the [user does not have the correct permissions](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/forum/threads/document-root-home-directory.7941/) (I get a 500 error when visiting the site). I am wondering how I go about changing those permissions.

```
# ps -ef|grep litespeed
```

Returns

```
root     24011     1  0 22:06 ?        00:00:00 openlitespeed (lshttpd - main)
root     24012 24011  0 22:06 ?        00:00:00 openlitespeed (lscgid)
nobody   24021 24011  0 22:06 ?        00:00:00 openlitespeed (lshttpd - #01)
nobody   24022 24011  0 22:06 ?        00:00:00 openlitespeed (lshttpd - #02)
root     24095 20775  0 22:15 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto litespeed
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try set up **suexec user/group** as this [image: screenshot] (the last 2 options) to your external app setting, accordingly to your **/var/www/html/public** owner/group.

but 500 error not necessarily means permission issue.

You can also try create a simple hello world or phpinfo page to test first.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your response. I changed the suEXEC user to root, which is the owner of that folder, and I am now getting a 503 error

Comment: If you do a simple hello world or phpinfo , does it also hit 503 ?

Comment: Nope! It was actually totally not related to users at all! You were right. I should have checked the error log. I forgot to run composer upgrade and so was throwing errors when trying to include autoload and bootsrap for Laravel. Thank you!